# Why is this Function<List<Person>,String> is not working?

Tags: java, java-8

I've working on Function and this I've already tried

```
Function<Person,String> byName = Person::getName;
System.out.println( byName.apply(list.get(1)) );
```

This worked and prints the Person's names at index 1;

But now I want to create `Function<List<Person>,String>` to iterate over all
the persons in the List

```
Function<List<Person>,String> allNames = a -> a.forEach(e-> e.getName());
System.out.println(allNames.apply(list));
```

Its throws an error as "void cannot be converted to String "

Comment: Because your function doesn't return a string, it just iterate the persons and gets their names without doing anything with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function package has this Two Functional Interface

1. Supplier
2. Consumer

According to Documentation ->

> Use Supplier if it takes nothing, but returns something.
>
> Use Consumer if it takes something, but returns nothing.

This following snippet solved my Problem ->

```
    Consumer<List<Person>> allNames = (a) -> a.forEach(e -> System.out.print(e.getName()+" "));
    allNames.accept(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

`forEach()` takes a consumer which applies a function to each element. It doesn't return anything, so you can't use it inside of a `System.out.println()` call. If you feel like you want to *return* something from a `forEach()`, chances are you want to `stream()` if necessary, then call `map()` instead.

However, staying closer to your first example, you likely want to call `forEach()` on your list instead, and then print out the result of the function on each elment there:

```
Function<Person, String> byName = Person::getName;
list.forEach(e -> System.out.println(byName.apply(e.getName())));
```

Comment: I did something Lilke this using Function and Stream API `Function<List<Person>,List<String>> allNamesInList =                               (List<Person> a) ->
        { 
            return a.stream().map(e->e.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        };
        System.out.println(allNamesInList.apply(list));`